# Searching for a fix to my problem about syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

[My Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSADx.png)

I do not know what causes this error! It´s the exact same code in the book I bought about python

I hope someone can help me and tell me what I am missing

def__init__(self, ma, mo, bj, pr):
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Thats the error message!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a space between `def` and `__init__`, `def__init__(self, ma, mo, bj, pr):` must be replaced with `def __init__(self, ma, mo, bj, pr):`

Answer (score 1):

There should be a space between the `def` and `__init__`.